# PostgreSQL combine multiple EXECUTE statements

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a PREPARE statement which is being called multiple times using EXECUTE.
To save database connection cost, we make a big query like:

```
PREPARE updreturn as update myTable set col1 = 1 where col2= $1 returning col3;
EXECUTE updreturn(1);
EXECUTE updreturn(2);
....
EXECUTE updreturn(10);
```

and send to the database.
However, I get the result for only the last EXECUTE statement.

Is there a way I could store these results in a temporary table and get all the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a transaction and a temporary table. And execute 3 queries:

**Query 1:** Start a Transaction (*I don't know what you are using to connect to the database*).

**Query 2:**

```
-- Create a Temporary Table to store the returned values
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_return (
    col3    text
) ON COMMIT DROP;

-- Prepare the Statement
PREPARE updreturn AS 
    WITH u AS (
        UPDATE myTable SET col1 = 1 WHERE col2= $1 RETURNING col3
    )
    INSERT INTO temp_return (col3) SELECT col3 FROM u;

EXECUTE updreturn(1);
EXECUTE updreturn(2);
.....
EXECUTE updreturn(10);

-- Deallocate the Statement
DEALLOCATE updreturn;

-- Actually return the results
SELECT * FROM temp_return;
```

**Query 3:** Commit the Transaction (*see note at Query 1*)

Without any other details about your complete scenario I can't tell you more, but you should get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a hack for that.

- Create a `result` table to store your results
- Create a `trigger` before update on `myTable`
- Inside that trigger add `INSERT INTO result VALUES(col3)`

So every time your `myTable` row is update also a value will be insert into `result`